# Prove $\sqrt{d_{1}(x,y)^{2} + d_{2}(x,y)^{2}}$ is a metric

Tags: metric-spaces

If $d_{1}(x,y)$ and $d_{2}(x,y)$ are distance metrics, is $\sqrt{d_{1}(x,y)^{2} + d_{2}(x,y)^{2}}$ also a metric? How do you prove this? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt{d_1(x,y)^2 + d_2(x,y)^2}$?

Comment: I can show it satisfies all of properties of a metric, except I am not sure about the triangle inequality

Comment: It might help to edit your question and add that part in so people know what you are having trouble with

Answer (score 2):

Just use triangle inequality for  $d_1$ and $d_2$ and then use the following:

$\|(a,b)+(c,d)\|\leq \|(a,b)\|+\|(c,d)\|$ with $a=d_1(x,z), b=d_2(x,z), c=d_1(z,y),d=d_2(z,y)$ where $\|(.,.)\|$ is the usual norm in $\mathbb R^{2}$.